# Textblob Translation issue into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, translation, textblob

```
This is my Data
d = {'col1': ["hola chica", "hello girl"], 'col2': [2, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

[see my Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktFqT.png)

Then I created this function

```
def translate(x):
    blob =TextBlob(x)
    return blob.translate(to='fr')
```

I called it here

```
df['translated'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x:translate(x))
```

When I print my dataframe to see the translated column I get results with letter by letter followed by comma. I cant figure out why it doesnt show the sentence

[see how my column translated looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFKru.png)

Any ideas why this is happening?

I need to be able to have the sentence without the commas thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately when you are using the apply method, you are returning a TextBlob object instead of a String and Pandas doesn't know exactly what to do with it (which is why you get the weird behavior).

To solve your issue, simply surround the code being returned with `str()`. Your final translate method looks like this

```
def translate(x):
    blob = TextBlob(x)
    return str(blob.translate(to='fr'))
```

and your output

```
    col1    col2    translated
0   hola chica  2   salut
1   hello girl  4   bonjour fille
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.